# Inserting multiple rss feeds into MYSQL with simplexml

Tags: php, mysql, xml, rss, simplexml

Below is my code to parse multiple rss feeds into a mysql db. 
I do something wrong in the foreach part I think, since there is no output. 
The db however, gets filled. When using 1 feed, the script works fine.
Anybody sees what I do wrong? Many thanks in advance :)

```
$feeds = ('https://www.ictu.nl/rss.xml', 'http://www.vng.nl/smartsite.dws?id=97817');
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feeds);

foreach($xml->channel->item as $item)
{
$date_format = "j-n-Y"; // 7-7-2008
echo date($date_format,strtotime($item->pubDate));  
         echo '<a href="'.$item->link.'" target="_blank">'.$item->title.'</a>';
         echo '<div>' . $item->description . '</div>';

mysql_query("INSERT INTO rss_feeds (id, title, description, link, pubdate) 
VALUES (
    '', 
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->title)."', 
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->description=htmlspecialchars(trim($item->description)))."', 
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->link)."', 
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->pubdate)."')");       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$feeds = array('https://www.ictu.nl/rss.xml', 'http://www.vng.nl/smartsite.dws?id=97817');
foreach( $feeds as $feed ) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);

    foreach($xml->channel->item as $item)
    {
    $date_format = "j-n-Y"; // 7-7-2008
    echo date($date_format,strtotime($item->pubDate));  
             echo '<a href="'.$item->link.'" target="_blank">'.$item->title.'</a>';
             echo '<div>' . $item->description . '</div>';

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO rss_feeds (id, title, description, link, pubdate) 
    VALUES (
        '', 
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->title)."', 
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->description=htmlspecialchars(trim($item->description)))."', 
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->link)."', 
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->pubdate)."')");       
    }
}
?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great, that did it! I was stupid to forget the accolades. One more question, regarding this script: I also must have done something wrong with the pubdate notation / date format and the strtotime: allthough the script echoes the time correctly,